# Building has many through relationship rails from existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a bit stuck on creating a form for a has many through relationship. At the moment my models are that Songs can have many Setlists and vice versa, through Allocations.

I'm currently working on an edit page, in which a user can add songs to a setlist. The view currently looks like this:

```
<h1>Edit a Setlist</h1>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span8">
      <%=form_for(@setlist) do|f|%>

         <%=f.label :date, "Set a date" %>
         <span><%=f.date_select :date%><span>

        <div>
          <div id="library">
          <%= render 'library' %>
          </div>

          <%= render 'songs_in_set' %> 

        </div>

         <%=f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

The library partial referred to above:

```
<table class= "table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Add to Set</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% @songs.each do |song| %>
            <tr>
               <td><%= song.title %></td>
               <td><%= song.artist %></td>
               <td><%= link_to "ADD", '#' %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to convert that link in the library partial to a form for creating a new allocation, thus adding a song to the set list.

The relevant bits from my controllers:
The setlist controller:

```
def edit
    @songs = Song.all(order: 'title')
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
  end

  def update

    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    if @setlist.update_attributes(params[:setlist])

      flash[:success] = "SAVED!"
      redirect_to setlist_path(@setlist)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

and the allocations controller:

def new
    @allocation = Allocation.new
  end

def create

```
@allocation = Allocation.new(params[:allocation])

if @allocation.save
 flash[:success] = "Songs added"
 redirect_to edit_setlist_path(@allocation.setlist_id)
else
     flash[:fail] = "Error"
 redirect_to edit_setlist_path(@allocation.setlist_id)
end
```

end

I know that I've got to do something along the lines of setlist.allocations.build but I'm having trouble getting the right parameters (getting each individual song id and the setlist id). I've tried putting a form for helper within the songs.each do loop but that didn't seem to work. I'm a bit lost so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `Setlist`:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :allocations, :dependent => :destroy
```

Then you can nest association fieldsets within your setlist form. In the library partial:

```
<td>
  <%= f.fields_for :allocations do |ff| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :song_id, song.id %>
    ...
  <% end %>
</td>
```

This should work if you want to create allocations for songs which exist already, but you might need something different for a scenario when you are also creating songs in the same form. I had a problem like that not long ago, and wasn't able to find a clean solution, but let me know and I can share that as well...